# How to show default layout on a proxy page in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt app whereby several pages are being proxied via `'@nuxtjs/proxy'`. The reason for this is because i am creating a new Nuxt app but refactoring a legacy Django app to run on Nuxt. Thereby i am converting individual pages into vue components, piece by piece.

I have a list of legacy pages that the app proxies:

```
proxy: [
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/store',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api'
  ],
```

I also have a default layout, that has a navbar that is used throughout the app. I would like this layout / navbar to appear in my `'http://127.0.0.1:8000/store'` proxy page. How would i do this?

Comment: I hope you know about this https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-layout/ where you can mention a different layout.

Comment: right but even with that layout, when i access 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/store', the default layout is not visible.